# How do I create low poly style terrain

Tags: modeling

How do I create a ico sphere type flat surface, like a low poly terrain for an island

I can create a surface using subdivide and triangulate but the result just isn't the same

Here is an example of what I desire:
[image: example]

Edit: Here is the best that I can do, and the faces just aren't rotated in the same way, and that's what I want to accomplish (notice that I'm quite new to this program) [image]

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What's the difference between your model and the one in the above image? Screenshots of _your_ models always help.

Comment: Have you tried using the decimate modifier? And making sure you're using hard shading rather than smooth shading on the particular object?

Comment: http://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secrets-to-creating-low-poly-illustrations-in-blender--cg-31770

Comment: Just for clarity sake I think  the term you were looking for is **Low Poly Style** modeling, in this case a a Low poly style island terrain. This as nothing to do with Icospheres, except the triangulated appearance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Albeit the somewhat vague description of your problem, let's give it a try...

Creating low poly models as shown in the above image require a little more polygons to start with. The more data Blender has to work with, the better the result.

Let's start with a nice terrain (in my case done with the ANT Landscape addon) that has a decent amount of geometry. My model has 16k faces.

[image: hipoly]

Now go to Properties Window - Modifiers - Add Modifier - Decimate

[image: add modifier]

In the Decimate modifier's settings chose "collapse", check "triangulate" and lower the ratio until you have the desired effect.

[image: decimate options]

This is what your model should look like (reduced to 3k faces).

[image: result]