# basic low Poly Illustrations mountains

Tags: modeling, animation

I am a beginner and I think this is a basic, I am trying to use the blender to create a basic Low Poly Illustrations mountains. So according to tutorials[image]

but all I could do with the tutorial's help is this [image]

Need help. What should i change to make it the one in the tutorials.
thanks in advance.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58507/how-to-model-low-poly-nature-terrain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn on ***Proportional Editing***:

[image]

From the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html?highlight=proportional%20editing):

> **Proportional Edit** is a way of transforming selected elements (such as vertices) while having that transformation affect other nearby elements. For example, having the movement of a single vertex cause the movement of unselected vertices within a given range. Unselected vertices that are closer to the selected vertex will move more than those farther from it (i.e. they will move proportionally relative to the location of the selected element
>
> **Influence**
>
> You can increase or decrease the radius of the proportional editing influence with the mouse wheel WheelUp, WheelDown or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd> respectively. As you change the radius, the points surrounding your selection will adjust their positions accordingly.

Comment: Keyboard Shortcut (Toggle Proportional Editing) - O Key