# Low poly/ cartoonish tropical island creation

Tags: unity

So I'm making a game in unity sort of like Sea of Thieves, which has a cartoonish feel to it.

What I've done so far, is create the shape of the island in blender, and then save the model to a folder in my unity project. Then I used the Object2Terrain script to make a terrain with the shape of the island.

What I'm currently stuck on, is making the rocks and cliffs around the island. I want to create something similar to the rocks/ cliffs in this:

[image]

https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/exterior/landmark/tropical-environment-pack

But every tutorial I find when searching "low poly cliff in blender" turns out to be bad.

Does anyone know what I could do in this situation? maybe they have a tutorial I haven't found they could leave a link for?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iP-ZAUA8Ga4 This might help.There are so many similar tutorials.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58507/how-to-model-low-poly-nature-terrain/58835#58835

Answer (score 1):

What i recommend is to use a tool called Bisect.
To do this,  subdivide a cube and apply Subdivision Surface to get a sphere-ish shape. 
Then to reach the Bisect tool, switch to edit mode, press space, search and there you go.
Press F6 and check "Fill". You can basicly slice pieces from your mesh. Then continue bicecting, till you get the shape you want. Scale the object to perfect your work.
I hope this little tip helped you, if you have any other questions or problems, let me know.

Source: https://youtu.be/G2CdYFgrP84

Comment: I will definitely look at it! I think it was exactly what I was looking for!