# How to make low poly water?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, unity

I'm creating a game in Unity3D and I'm using blender as my main modeling software, The problem here is that I don't know how to make a low poly water cube, I've seen that a lot of people makes this using a plane, but I need to make a cube, and I can´t find how to make this in blender render or in Unity without A package from Asset Store.
It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58507/how-to-model-low-poly-nature-terrain

Answer (score 4):

[image: final]
*Rendered in LuxCoreRender just for fancy look.*

I'm not sure which cube you are referring to, so I'll first send you to some fluid sim 101 and then I'll show you what have I used for this scene.

1. [Blender Docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/index.html)
2. [Blender fluid simulation tutorial in one minute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKw0nIOiBOM)

Now you know how to make simple Fluid sim and here is how I've achieved this low poly look:

**Domain:**

I've used resolution - 24. You can tweak it as needed. Lower value = lower poly count.

[image: domain]

**Inflow Object (Cube):**

Here I've changed only **Inlfow Velocity** to **-5m/s** on **Z** axis. To speed up fluid.

[image: inlfow]

**Cycles:**

If you want to render it with **Cycles** you can use this material for **Domain** object. But if you are gonna to use it with Unity this is optional.

[image: cycles]